# Installing multiple Moodle package

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, moodle

Can I install multiple `Moodle` versions on my local machine for development purpose? Currently, I've installed the latest Moodle `dev` version and it works fine. I'm able to use `MySQL` and `phpMyAdmin` at my will.

How will multiple Moodle packages effect `MySQL` or `phpMyAdmin`?

Any blogs/posts will be appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Installation for your seventh Moodle instance should go like this:

- unpack all files into Moodle7;
- create moodledata7 folder;
- create moodle7 database in phpmyadmin;
- do not create a separate user, just grant all privileges to the same user as previous 6 installations;
- open localhost/moodle7 and proceed with install as normal, point install wizard to the above folders and databases.

If you want to clone your existing moodle installation, copy moodle to moodle2, moodledata to moodledata2, clone database moodle to moodle2. Then edit `config.php` in the root of moodle2 folder to point at correct `dirroot`, `wwwroot` and database.

Then do a search and replace in the database (there's a good howto on stackoverflow) to change any hyperlinks in your moodle courses, forum posts, etc. from moodle to moodle2.

Answer (score 1):

Moodle + multiple instance + cron:

I have more "moodle" virtual domains an my directory structure is:

```
/var/www/html/main.moodle (directory with moodle installation)
/var/www/html/sub1.moodle.site -> symlink to main.moodle
/var/www/html/sub2.moodle.site -> symlink to main.moodle
/var/www/html/sub3.moodle.site -> symlink to main.moodle
```

Here is my config.php with cron functionality for multiple sites.

```
define('MOODLE_NO_DOMAIN', 'none');
$domain = MOODLE_NO_DOMAIN;

if ( defined('CLI_SCRIPT') && CLI_SCRIPT == true) {
        // CALLED FROM COMMANDLINE - cron.php etc ..
        preg_match('/^(.*\/)*(.*\.moodle\.site)\/.*$/',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],$matches);
        if ( count($matches) > 0 ) {
                $domain = $matches[count($matches) - 1];
        }
} else {
        // CALLED FROM BROWSER
        $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

// HERE AS ABOVE FROM THOMAS VAN DEN HEUVEL

```
switch ($domain) {
    // configuration for subdomain 1
    case 'sub1.domain.com':
        $CFG->dbname = 'sub1_moodle'; // if your database is called sub1_moodle for this subdomain
        $CFG->wwwroot = 'http://sub1.moodle.site'; // no trailing slash
        $CFG->dataroot = '/path/to/sub1data/'; // depends on where you put your datadir
        break;
    // configuration for subdomain 2
    case 'sub2.domain.com':
        $CFG->dbname = 'sub2_moodle'; // if your database is called sub2_moodle for this subdomain
        $CFG->wwwroot = 'http://sub2.moodle.site'; // no trailing slash
        $CFG->dataroot = '/path/to/sub2data/'; // depends on where you put your datadir
        break;
    // et cetera
    default:
        // ... redirect to info page with moodle links
}
```

$CFG->dirroot = '/var/www/html/main.moodle';

Cron tasks must be called with absolute or relative subdomain path:

```
php /var/www/html/sub1.moodle.site/admin/cli/cron.php
```

or

```
php sub1.moodle.site/admin/cli/cron.php
```

I call all of the subdomains crons with one very simple script :

```
#! /bin/bash
WWW_ROOT="/var/www/html"
DIRS="sub1.moodle.site sub2.moodle.site sub3.moodle site"
for dir in $DIRS
do
        echo "$WWW_ROOT/$dir"
        php "$WWW_ROOT/$dir/admin/cli/cron.php"
done
```

Comment: Consider editing your post with guidelines from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ubuntu, but yes, you can install multiple Moodle versions in a system, on the same server.

Just name the folder different, create a differently named database in PHPMyAdmin, and also name the 'moodledata' folder accordingly. Everything should be fine just then.